# Keep column names for createDummyFeatures "reference" (n-1)

Tags: r, dummy-variable, mlr

I have this kind of data.

```
library(dplyr)

glimpse(samp)
Observations: 5
Variables: 5
$ review_count               <int> 68, 3, 7, 9, 5
$ Alcohol                    <fct> full_bar, NA, full_bar, beer_and_wi...
$ BikeParking                <fct> True, NA, False, NA, NA
$ BusinessAcceptsBitcoin     <fct> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ BusinessAcceptsCreditCards <fct> True, NA, NA, True, True
```

I want to create 1-p dummy features. The `createDummyFeatures` function of the `mlr` package has the option `reference` to do this.

```
library(mlr)
dummy = createDummyFeatures(samp, target = "review_count", method = "reference")
```

The problem is that it doesn´t keep the original column names.

```
glimpse(dummy)
Observations: 5
Variables: 6
$ review_count     <int> 68, 3, 7, 9, 5
$ Alcohol.full_bar <dbl> 1, NA, 1, 0, NA
$ Alcohol.none     <dbl> 0, NA, 0, 0, NA
$ True             <dbl> 1, NA, 0, NA, NA
$ True.1           <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ True.2           <dbl> 1, NA, NA, 1, 1
```

The question is how can I keep them?

An Idea is to create them by the `1-of-n`method and then remove all columns which contain "False".

```
dummy2 = createDummyFeatures(samp, target = "review_count")

dummy2 = dummy2 %>%
  select(-contains("False"))

glimpse(dummy2)
Observations: 5
Variables: 7
$ review_count                    <int> 68, 3, 7, 9, 5
$ Alcohol.beer_and_wine           <dbl> 0, NA, 0, 1, NA
$ Alcohol.full_bar                <dbl> 1, NA, 1, 0, NA
$ Alcohol.none                    <dbl> 0, NA, 0, 0, NA
$ BikeParking.True                <dbl> 1, NA, 0, NA, NA
$ BusinessAcceptsBitcoin.True     <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ BusinessAcceptsCreditCards.True <dbl> 1, NA, NA, 1, 1
```

However, I don´t know if it is the same as n-1 especially for the factors with more then 2 levels (The dummy coding is for an XGBoost regression where "review count" is the target variable).

```
dput(samp)
structure(list(review_count = c(68L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 5L), Alcohol = structure(c(2L, 
NA, 2L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("beer_and_wine", "full_bar", "none"
), class = "factor"), BikeParking = structure(c(2L, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA), .Label = c("False", "True"), class = "factor"), BusinessAcceptsBitcoin = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("False", 
"True"), class = "factor"), BusinessAcceptsCreditCards = structure(c(2L, 
NA, NA, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("False", "True"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

**Edit**

For those who have the same problem, I fixed this issue using `caret`.

```
library(caret)
dummy_dat = dummyVars("~ .", data = samp, fullRank = T)

dat = data.frame(predict(dummy_dat, newdata = samp))
```

Comment: The column `Alcohol` results in two columns of dummy variables. How should these columns be named?

Comment: The column `Alcohol` (and others which are not in this short sample) has more than two factor levels (NA values aside). The names are not that important as long as I recognize them. The goal is to avoid multicollinearity.